# Is there a way to identify which data has been selected with the sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, feed

I have a sql statement:

```
$feed=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_by=? OR id=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
$feed->bind_param("ii",$friend['id'],$like[id]);
$feed->execute();
```

The `$friend['id']` is the id of a user's friend, `$like[id]` is the id of a like by the user's friend.

The posts fetched with this query appear in a page.

**What I want is I want to know which all posts have been posted by the user's friends (Which all posts have been fetched using `$friends['id'])` and which all posts have been liked by the user's friends and appear in the feed(Which all posts have been fetched using `$like['id']`)**

I want to know all possibilities I can try to achieve what I want.

I have tried varying my query with `UNION ALL` but it shows errors and I could'nt achieve what I want.

**Currently there are no errors but I want the user to know how this post appeared in the newsfeed.**

Hope you all get a good idea about my question and all types of hacks are also accepted as I want in someway to achieve the result I would also agree to change mt query nature.

Please comment for more info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First fix the query please, two placeholders 3 values

Comment: Sorry for that @Hanky웃Panky. Can you give me an answer I surely want one.

Comment: you placeholders and parmaters number do not match, two placeholders then bind two parameters only

Comment: Sorry for that @Sourabh. Can you give me an answer please I beg you for I fixed the question though

Comment: There will also be some overlap, where a row matches both friend and like criteria. What do you want then?

Comment: StuartLC is saying that if a friend likes their own post or a mutual friend's post, both criteria will match. I assume in that case it will be explained as a post by a friend rather than a like by a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, post_by = ?postId AS post_by_friend
FROM posts
WHERE post_by = ?postId OR
      id = ?friendId
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

`post_by_friend` will be 1 if it matched the first condition, otherwise 0. I haven't benchmarked it, but this method should be faster than StuartLC's `UNION` suggestion.

Comment: Good idea, in fact, can also add the `likes` match as a column in the same way, and thus both flags set if both matched without adding dupe rows. But will also need to bind using named parameters (as we've now got 3 positional parameters).

Comment: I never use MySQL prepared statements, so I wasn't sure of the syntax - that's why I stuck with question marks. I've updated my answer to use the same syntax as yours. Another column could certainly be added, but a `post_by_friend` value of 0 naturally implies a `likes` value of 1. (Not always the reverse as you point out, of course.) The exact output of your `UNION` could be replicated with `IF(post_by = ?postId, 'Friend', 'Like') AS HowFound`, but that's really just slowing things down to no good end.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how can I use `post_by_friend` with if() in php I have tried if($post_by_friend) and if('post_by_friend') but both did'not work please help me out @Mikkel

Comment: Sorry about the inline code, but: `$result = $feed->get_result(); while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { if ($row['post_by_friend']) { var_dump($row); } }`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo, but `$like[id]` in your original code is deprecated and will throw an E_NOTICE error. You should use a string literal as an array key instead, ie. `$like['id']`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is break the query up on its 'OR' clause into a UNION of two separate queries, and add a marker column to indicate whether the row was found by `friend` or by `like`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
   SELECT *, 'Friend' AS HowFound
   FROM posts 
   WHERE post_by= ?postId

UNION 

   SELECT *, 'Like' AS HowFound
   FROM posts 
   WHERE id= ?friendId AND post_by <> ?postId
) x
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

You'll want to exclude rows which match both `friend` and post `classifications` from one of the selects, otherwise it will be reported twice (or, otherwise your app will need to combine them).

I'm no PHP guru, but I'm sure there is a way to name the parameters to allow the above exclusion.

The derived table is needed to order and restrict the overall result.